# Other PCAP network software other than TCPREPLAY?

Tags: tcp

I would like to find out if there are more other useful softwares with the same functions or more like TCPREPLAY which has the ability to "playback" PCAP files? Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is basically using TCPREPLAY as there are almost no other replay packets software available. Its suggested to use the Windows version instead as you are able to configure the files better.